# How to Display Data from Database in React with DataTable

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm new in javascript and I'm using react. I want to display data from the database using dataTable in Material Dashboard 2 but, the data doesn't display and there is no error message. Here is my code :

```
<DataTable
  table={{
    columns: [
      { Header: "Kode", accessor: "Kode", width: "15%" },
      { Header: "Nama", accessor: "Nama" },
      { Header: "Semester", accessor: "Semester", width: "12%" },
      { Header: "SKS", accessor: "SKS", width: "12%" },
    ],
    rows: [
      data.map((item) => [
        {
          Kode: data.code,
          Nama: "RPS MPSI",
          Semester: "5",
          SKS: 3,
        },
      ]),
    ],
  }}
/>;
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more that which libarary are you using for DataTable ?

Comment: i'm using material dashboard 2 from creative tim, when i use dumy data the code work but when i'm trying use database the data doesn't display but when im trying to use console, the data exist